# Separate each map in a list of map

Tags: java, collections

I have a map as : `Map<Integer, Map<LocalDate, CustomObject>>`
I want to perform operations on each value of the inner map.
sample example of my data in map :

```
<1, Map<2018-12-01, "A">
       <2018-12-02, "A">
       <2018-12-03, "A">
       <2018-12-04, "A">
       <2018-12-05, "A">>

<2, Map<2018-12-01, "B">
       <2018-12-02, "B">
       <2018-12-03, "B">
       <2018-12-04, "B">
       <2018-12-05, "B">>

<3, Map<2018-12-01, "C">
       <2018-12-02, "C">
       <2018-12-03, "C">
       <2018-12-04, "C">
       <2018-12-05, "C">>
```

I have tried adding the values of map as a list of map; Like :

```
List<Map<LocalDate, CustomObject>>
```

But I am unable to achieve the operation that I want to perform

What I need is to add all the elements key wise and generate a resultant Map.
ie; I need some thing like INTO A RESULTANT MAP

```
2018-12-01 : A+B+C
2018-12-02 : A+B+C
2018-12-03 : A+B+C
```

Comment: which JDK version you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to obtain a `Stream` of the entries of all the inner Maps, and then collect them as you wish:

```
Map<Integer, Map<LocalDate, CustomObject>> input = ...

Map<LocalDate,List<CustomObject>> grouped =
    input.values() // Collection<Map<LocalDate, CustomObject>>
         .stream() // Stream<Map<LocalDate, CustomObject>>
         .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) // Stream<Map.Entry<LocalDate, CustomObject>>
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                           Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: It's more like a Map<Integer, List<Map<LocalDate, CustomObject>>>

Comment: @MS90 Based on the OP's stated desired output - `2018-12-01 : A+B+C...`, I think what I posted may be the desired output

Comment: I somehow wrote below your answer, I was reffering to his "I have a map as : Map<Integer, Map<LocalDate, CustomObject>> I want to perform operations on each value of the inner map. sample example of my data in map :"

Comment: This didn't directly gave me the expected result but was 98% done by this. I just then needed to merge the grouped list instances of CustomObject to abtained the desired output. Thanks @Eran

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate both outer and inner maps and add entries into a new multi-map:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<CustomObject>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
yourMap.forEach((k1, v1) -> 
     v1.forEach((k2, v2) -> 
         result.computeIfAbsent(k2, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(v2)));
```

This uses `Map.computeIfAbsent` to create a new list if there is no entry for the key. Then the `CustomObject` instance is added to the list. Here `k1` is the outer map's key, `v1` is the inner map, `k2` is the `LocalDate` and `v2` is the `CustomObject` instance.